# Scan jar files before deploying to a PaaS (Cloud Foundry)

Tags: java, jar, cloud-foundry

We are developing `Spring boot` Apps and have those deployed in `Cloud Foundry` PaaS.

There are certain restrictions in our Enterprise that only approved versions of Libraries needs to be used for App Development and we would like to scan the Jar files before getting deployed in Cloud Foundry

I would like to have this implemented in Cloud Foundry itself .. Or is there any other way ? such that having a Gradle Task scan the Jar and then deploy in `Cloud Foundry` ?

Please suggest a good pattern to scan the Jars before deploying..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right pattern is to maintain your scanned jars in a tool like Artifactory.

Change your maven pom files or your gradle build file to use the Artifactory for the jars needed in your build processes.

This approach allows you to control not only external jars but also custom jars that you have created internally.